# Configure AWS Redshift on Ubuntu 18.04 and use it with pyodbc

Tags: amazon-redshift, pyodbc, ubuntu-18.04

When I try to connect to my DSN using pyodbc I am getting following error:

> python3: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1' with`
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I have tried different solution like reinstalling libudev1 etc. but nothing is working.

I tried to connect to using 16.04 VM and I am getting

> could not connect to server: Connection timed out Is the server
>   running on host xxxxxx and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5439?

pyodbc works fine on 16.04 but not connecting.

*PS: I am using VPN tunnel for redshift connections*

Comment: can you try psycopg2 or sqlalchemy instead for the connection?

Comment: No. I am not defining models using Django for that DB. I am just accessing data from it and other apps are using pyodbc that cannot be changed

Comment: ok don't try it then :) - you dont need a model BTW just the sql.

Comment: You are right. Actually I am trying  psycopg2 and I am getting connection refused. I think my traffic is not going through openvpn tunnel.

Comment: Yes that looks like the case for your second (16.04) server. you need to fix that first. maybe you need to modify your redshift security group to allow this new ip?

Answer (score 0):

Problem with odbc is that Amazon Redshift driver is compiled using different version of GCC than in 18.04. It works on 16.04 and below but not on 18.04.