# Python3 Relink issue while importing opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, segmentation-fault

### Question:

I have a segmentation fault after trying to import a freshly compiled version of the latest available [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) from [github](https://github.com/opencv) on Ubuntu 18.04.

Here is the error message I got while trying to import `cv2` in [Python 3](https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.0/):

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Aug 20 2019, 17:12:48) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
python3: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
python3: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

My Ubuntu; `5.0.0-29-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux`

From where I cloned OpenCV; https://github.com/opencv/opencv

Related threads;
[getting error while importing cv2 module in ubuntu amazon instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56347458/getting-error-while-importing-cv2-module-in-ubuntu-amazon-instance)
[Configure AWS Redshift on Ubuntu 18.04 and use it with pyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55166840/configure-aws-redshift-on-ubuntu-18-04-and-use-it-with-pyodbc)
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444697/cannot-run-python-file-asks-to-relink-libraries
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19375

None of the solutions presented worked as **I do not have any NVidia graphic chips** on my laptop;

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
```

**Notice**:
I need to compile OpenCV from sources because I want to use [SIFT](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Elowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf) and [SURF](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/%7Esurf/eccv06.pdf) [detectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_detection_(computer_vision)) and [descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_descriptor) and they are no more available when OpenCV is installed with [`apt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt.8.html):

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'4.2.0'

>>> cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()    

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0)     
/io/opencv_contrib/modules/xfeatures2d/src/sift.cpp:1210:    
error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented)     
This algorithm is patented and is excluded in this configuration;    
Set OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE CMake option and rebuild the library in    
function 'create'
```

Comment: yo.. did u manage to fix this problem.. i am also having a slimier problem. think it has something do with the GPU drivers or configuration. i dont't know how to fix

Comment: I didn't fix it for the moment. If I found any way to improve this, I will update the main post.

Comment: It would be nice if you had found a solution already.

Answer (score 11):

This seems to be caused by version dependency issues.
I faced the same problem, Run the below command
 `apt install python3-opencv`

This will solve the problem.

Comment: I must compile opencv from sources to be able to run tests using SIFT and SURF keypoints & descriptors (+many others), which are no more available when opencv is installed with apt: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039224/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-xfeatures2d-python-opencv-2 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52305578/sift-cv2-xfeatures2d-sift-create-not-working-even-though-have-contrib-instal

Comment: It didn't solve my problem, and neither did the links posted by s.k. As for my issue, it's related to `user:~/$ jupyter qtconsole
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3.8: Relink `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the error was solved by installing the OpenCV headers `sudo apt install libopencv-dev`. Typically I do this `apt` install before trying to `pip` install the OpenCV Python bindings

Comment: It didn't solve the issue as I am building opencv from sources.

Comment: It didn't solve my problem either. As for my issue, it's related to `user:~/$ jupyter qtconsole
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3.8: Relink `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Answer (score 3):

In my case

```
python3.6: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
python3.6: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
```

was generated by

```
$ python3.6
import tvm
```

and resolved by installation of a missing library. I found out this was missing by using a different version of python, as has been suggested elsewhere. In particular I found

```
$ python3.7
import tvm
```

reports (accurately) on a missing library. Once the missing library was installed for python3.6

```
$ python3.6 -m pip install <missing_library>
```

the problem went away.

So the problem is not specific to OpenCV or CuDNN. It seems to be a problem in the error reporting in python3.6.

Comment: Solved my issue too. python3.8 reported missing libnccl2 package.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. In my situation, the problem was related to the CuDNN.

```
Cuda: 10.2
CuDNN: tried both versions 7.6.5 and 8.0.1
```

When I compiled OpenCV 4.4.0 from github **without** the CuDNN enabled, the error was gone.
In another words, **don't include** these cmake flags when you compile the OpenCV:

```
-D WITH_CUDNN=ON \
-D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON \
```

If you need the CuDNN support, the problem might be the CuDNN is not linked properly after installation.
Make sure you run the command below after you install the CuDNN

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Run that again after the OpenCV compilation ends.